# external drive not able to start up Mac

Tags: macos, external-disk

Good day, I want to install macOS Big Sur onto a thumb drive but when I try to install it, I am told that 'This disk can't be used to start up your computer'.  How can I fix it?

Here is the output from `diskutil list` in terminal:

```
 /dev/disk0 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *251.0 GB   disk0
   1:                        EFI ⁨EFI⁩                     209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2:                 Apple_APFS ⁨Container disk1⁩         250.8 GB   disk0s2

/dev/disk1 (synthesized):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      APFS Container Scheme -                      +250.8 GB   disk1
                                 Physical Store disk0s2
   1:                APFS Volume ⁨MacSSD - Data⁩           206.7 GB   disk1s1
   2:                APFS Volume ⁨Preboot⁩                 544.5 MB   disk1s2
   3:                APFS Volume ⁨Recovery⁩                624.3 MB   disk1s3
   4:                APFS Volume ⁨MacSSD⁩                  15.3 GB    disk1s4
   5:              APFS Snapshot ⁨com.apple.os.update-...⁩ 15.3 GB    disk1s4s1
   6:                APFS Volume ⁨VM⁩                      1.1 MB     disk1s6

/dev/disk2 (disk image):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        +13.1 GB    disk2
   1:                        EFI ⁨EFI⁩                     209.7 MB   disk2s1
   2:                  Apple_HFS ⁨Shared Support⁩          12.8 GB    disk2s2

/dev/disk3 (external, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *505.4 MB   disk3
   1:                  Apple_HFS ⁨Untitled⁩                505.4 MB   disk3s1
```

Comment: Is the flash drive GPT partitioned?  Is the filesystem on it APFS?

Comment: What Mac is it precisely? Is Secure Boot disabled?

Comment: In answer to @MarcWilson yes and yes.

Comment: In answer to @Tetsujin it is a MacBook Pro (Retina, 15-inch, Mid 2014). I am not sure, what is Secure Boot?

Comment: @Hogarth A 2014 MBP doesn't have Secure Boot.  So don't worry about that.

Comment: Ok, cool. How should I proceed?

Comment: Add the result of `diskutil list` in Terminal to your question [copy/paste, select, then use Ctrl/K to format it as 'code'.]

Comment: How do I add it to the question?

Comment: Use the [edit](https://apple.stackexchange.com/posts/467750/edit) button directly beneath the question.

Comment: Ah I see, silly me. Done.

Comment: Is disk3 your intended target? It will need to be formatted APFS & is going to need at least 16GB free space, probably twice that to have any chance of being useable. [It is also going to be dog slow even if it does work.]

Comment: yes disk 3 is the target. I formatted it in APFS, what's next?

Comment: …a bigger drive;)

Comment: I looked it up - the OS itself needs 22GB. I wouldn't attempt to install it on anything smaller than 40GB.

Comment: Oh, I see. Thanks!